# Give documents greater weighting for searches?

Tags: 2007, search

Is it possible to customise SharePoint search so that certain documents in a Document Library could be given greater weight in search results based upon whether or not they were flagged (by adding an additional column) as important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might not be completely what you are lookin for but SharePoint offers  a functionality called "Authoritative Pages".

> Authoritative pages are those that link to the most relevant information. Search uses this list to calculate the rank of every page in the index. There might be many authoritative Web pages in your enviornment. Type the most valuable in the topmost text box. You also have the option of specifying second and third-level authorities in the lower text boxes.
>   Enter one full URL per line. Example: http://intranet/site-directory.html.

You can specify the authoritative pages on "http://ssp/admin/_layouts/editrelevancesettings.aspx"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have looked at Best Bets as a solution, but I figured I'd throw that out there and see if you have tried that.  Here's a few links to get you started:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/add-edit-and-delete-keyword-best-bets-HA001160577.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc835625(v=office.12).aspx

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Matt, thanks for your answer. I need it to be be for particular documents such as our current HR policy. I need people to be able to type HR policy and it will retrieve the most current one. So say 2010 just got superseded by 2011 yesterday, I need that to be the top result even though it has limited views and is only new.

Comment: well, that is really where the best bets come in!

Comment: Exactly, it's what we looked at early on when we wanted to generate our own weight to search results.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though what you want is a managed property. Your users can then use property filters in their search queries (e.g. Importance:High). You could also use it to define a scope to make it easier for users to locate the high importance documents.